# android studio onclickListener error (55,48)

Tags: android, this, onclicklistener, android-context

I've created `DBHelper` class as a database of my app. I want to save my data when I click on the button.

This error occured:

```
Error:(55, 48) error: constructor DBHelper in class DBHelper cannot be applied to given types;
required: Context
found: <anonymous OnClickListener>
reason: actual argument <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion
```

I wrote this code:

```
DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this); dbHelper.saveData(DataObjects);
```

Comment: Yea post code but I think that the problem is "this"

Answer (score 0):

As your code does not state where you execute the given snippet i assume that you try to execute this inside an `OnClickListener` (As stated in the exception)

Try to do the following:

```
DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(MyActivity.this); 
dbHelper.saveData(DataObjects);
```

Replace `MyActivity.this` with the name of your `Activity` which is your `Context`.